# Only download Firebase snapshots that have child key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My data structure looks like this (removed unnecessary parts):

```
{
  "threads" : {
    "PUSHID" : {
      "info" : {
        "members" : {
          "uid" : true,
          "uid2" : true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to write some javascript to pull snapshots of threads a user is in, but I can't figure out a way for it to work without pulling snapshots of each thread. This is my code now that pulls each thread snapshot.

```
firebase.database().ref('threads').on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasChild('info/members/' + userUid)) {
        // Display thread info
    }
});
```

I tried to make a query with `.orderByChild('info/members/' + userUid)` and removing null snapshots, but I would have to add a `.indexOn` for each `userUid` which is obviously not practical.

Answer (score 0):

Your current structure makes it easy/efficient to look up the users for a thread. But your use case is to look up the threads for a user. You'll need to augment your data model to allow the use-case:

```
{
  "user_threads" : {
    "uid": {
      "PUSHID": true,
      "PUSHID2": true
    },
    "uid2": {
      "PUSHID": true,
      "PUSHID3": true
    }
  }
}
```

And then read it with:

```
firebase.database().ref('user_threads/'+userUid).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  ...
});
```

Modifying/expanding your data model to match the use-cases of your app is quite common when using NoSQL databases.

Comment: I also have to take into account security and other operations I want to execute. The structure in my question is made so I could make security rules to limit only owners to make modifications to who is in each thread. I don't know how I would do security rules to prohibit users from adding themselves to threads they're not supposedly to belong to if I were to adopt the data structure you're suggesting.